# Django giving me local ip always on my site

Tags: python, django, geoip

I am using django-ipware for getting the Public IP of the user

https://github.com/un33k/django-ipware

My site is hosted on by virtual machine with `djnago , mod_wsgi , apache`

This is my code

```
    g = GeoIP()
    ip_address = get_ip_address_from_request(self.request)
    raise Exception(ip_address)
```

It gave me `127.0.0.1`

I am accessing it from my other computer on same network.

how can i get my public ip

I also tried this as well

```
PRIVATE_IPS_PREFIX = ('10.', '172.', '192.', )

def get_client_ip(request):
"""get the client ip from the request
"""
remote_address = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
# set the default value of the ip to be the REMOTE_ADDR if available
# else None
ip = remote_address
# try to get the first non-proxy ip (not a private ip) from the
# HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
if x_forwarded_for:
    proxies = x_forwarded_for.split(',')
    # remove the private ips from the beginning
    while (len(proxies) > 0 and
            proxies[0].startswith(PRIVATE_IPS_PREFIX)):
        proxies.pop(0)
    # take the first ip which is not a private one (of a proxy)
    if len(proxies) > 0:
        ip = proxies[0]

return ip
```

It returned me `192.168.0.10` my local computer ip

Comment: 1. Read this 
[question][1]
 2. Read documentation of VM



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django

Comment: @AlokTiwari i read that post already and i got my solution from that post . but could not find solution

Comment: You're not going to get your public IP on your lan because it is never going through that interface to be proxied.

Comment: @DivinusVox so u mean , if i host that code on my VPS server online , then will my code work

Comment: Yes, if a router converts packet to another network, it adds itself as the host ip and appends a different header (usually HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR) to the packet saying where it originally came from. Because you're on a LAN, it's never bridging networks.

Comment: If you hit an external host it will probably work fine.

Answer (score 1):

django-ipware attempts to get the client's (e.g. browser) public (externally route-able) IP address and it fails to do so, therefore, it returns '127.0.0.1' (local loopback, IPv4) indicating the failure as per its documentation (version 0.0.1).

That happens since you have your server running on the same (private) network as your own local computer. (192.168.x.x private block)

You can upgrade to version django-ipware>=0.0.5 which supports both IPv4 & IPv6 and use it as below.

```
# if you want the real IP address (public and externally route-able)
from ipware.ip import get_real_ip
ip = get_real_ip(request)
if ip is not None:
   # your server got the client's real public ip address
else:
   # your server doesn't have a real public ip address for user


# if you want the best matched IP address (public and/or private)
from ipware.ip import get_ip
ip = get_ip(request)
if ip is not None:
   # your server got the client's real ip address
else:
   # your server doesn't have a real ip address for user

####### NOTE:
# A `Real` IP address is the IP address of the client accessing your server 
# and not that of any proxies in between.
# A `Public` IP address is an address that is publicly route-able on the internet.
```