# TastyPie Authentication from the same server

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have an API in TastyPie thats consumed on the same domain. I only want to allow requests to come from my server.

TastyPie has a number of different **Authentication** options, however I cannot use **Session Authentication** because no one logs in and a **API Key** could be view in my script.

So I was thinking that I could somehow validate the post with a with **Django csrf token**. Is this possible any examples (I've search) or is there an option I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django) provides the following method to getting the request IP address:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

You could try coupling this with a custom `Authentication` class as follows:

```
class IpAuthentication(Authentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        return get_client_ip(request) in SETTINGS.ALLOWED_IPS:
```

You would have to populate your own `SETTINGS.ALLOWED_IPS` list.  This however is [not a foolproof method](https://serverfault.com/questions/381393/can-the-ip-address-for-an-http-request-be-spoofed) as IP addresses can be faked.