# how to get the ip address who are accessing my website using django for python

Tags: python, django

I have created web application. I need to get the IP address of the clients who are accessing my website and need to count the ip address for to find out how many users view this site. Can anyone give some ideas for to do this concepts. Then I referred some idea like:

```
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
```

Here `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` referred by?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is with:

```
request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
```

If your app server is behind a proxy, see this more advanced solution (using the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` you mentioned):

- [How do I get user IP address in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django/4581997#4581997)

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use [django-ipware](https://github.com/un33k/django-ipware) for get correct IP. This django app will give you 99% correct result. I am using this app and i am always getting correct result.

Note: I have given 99% success rating a per my previous working experience.