# Django: Request REMOTE_ADDR is void in production

Tags: django, http

I have an extrange problem in prodution enviroment with django:

In local I do a POST and use client's IP which is in:

```
request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

This gives me the IP of the client. But when the same code runs in a production server its void; `REMOTE_ADDR` is `''`

Why does it happens?

EDIT: I use nginx with gunicorn

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django The syntax is a little different, and it works for me both locally and in production.

Comment: You need to pass the `REMOTE_ADDR` header to the wsgi process. How to do that depends on your setup. Do you use a reverse proxy? gunicorn? Apache or Nginx?

Comment: @knbk gunicorn and nginx. How can I do it in that server?

Comment: @blagae thanks, with the accepted response of that questions works. :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are running `gunicorn` as a socket (not a TCP connection).  If so that's by [design](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/797).