# Django log user IP for user_login_failed signal

Tags: python, django, ip, signals

I would like to log the user IP address in my Django application, specifically for login, logout and failed login events. I'm using Django builtin functions as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_logged_out, user_login_failed
from ipware.ip import get_ip
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def log_logged_in(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    logger.info("%s User %s successfully logged in" % (get_ip(request), user))

def log_logged_out(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    logger.info("%s User %s successfully logged out" % (get_ip(request), user))

def log_login_failed(sender, credentials, **kwargs):
    logger.warning("%s Authentication failure for user %s" % ("...IP...", credentials['username']))

user_logged_in.connect(log_logged_in)
user_logged_out.connect(log_logged_out)
user_login_failed.connect(log_login_failed)
```

The issue is that I haven't found a way to get the IP for the `user_login_failed` signal since this function does not have the `request` in the parameters (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals). The `credentials` parameter is a dictionary that only contains the `username` and `password` fields.

How could I get the IP address for this signal?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `user_login_failed` singal don't pass request as argument.

Checkout `django-axes` — https://github.com/django-pci/django-axes/

It uses a custom view decorator to track failed logins.

https://github.com/django-pci/django-axes/blob/master/axes/decorators.py#L273

Answer (score 3):

I just found in newer Django version (I am using 2.1) has updated this and now it includes the request object in the user_login_failed signal:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_login_failed

Answer (score 0):

You could override the login form and intercept it there.
It has the request at that stage.

```
import logging
from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
from django import forms

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class AuthenticationForm(AdminAuthenticationForm):
    def clean(self):
        # to cover more complex cases:
        # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        try:
            data = super(AuthenticationForm, self).clean()
        except forms.ValidationError:
            log.info('Login Failed (%s) from (%s)', self.cleaned_data.get('username'), ip)
            raise

        if bool(self.user_cache):
            log.info('Login Success (%s) from (%s)', self.cleaned_data.get('username'), ip)
        else:
            log.info('Login Failed (%s) from (%s)', self.cleaned_data.get('username'), ip)

        return data
```

To install it into the site you need to attach it to django.contrib.admin.site.login_form

I would suggest doing it in your App's ready() method like so:

```
from django.contrib.admin import site as admin_site

class Config(AppConfig):
    ...

    def ready(self):
        # Attach the logging hook to the login form
        from .forms import AuthenticationForm
        admin_site.login_form = AuthenticationForm
```