# how to give some unique id to each anonymous user in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to create a table(postgres) that stores data about what items were viewed by what user. authenticated users are no problem but how can I tell one anonymous user from another anonymous user? This is needed for analysis purposes.

maybe store their IP address as unique ID? How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should use cookies.

When a user that is not authenticated makes a request, look for a cookie named whatever ("nonuserid" in this case). If the cookie is not present it means it's a new user so you should set the cookie with a random id. If it's present you can use the id in it to identificate the anonymous user.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1

Use the IP Address. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581997/1108052). There is no need to write the IP into the session because you could always get the client IP when you receive a request.

#### Option 2

Generate the unique ID by the `uuid`, as the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) said. And set the ID in the session with a given name, suppose it `USER_ID`.

When you get the request from a user, check if the `USER_ID` in session. If so, read the value of it and write a record to database like `user id visit page X`. If not, generate and set.

Comment: Using an ip address is a bad idea. Some isps are load balancing traffic using multiple proxies, meaning a single session can have many ip addresses. Second, it is common for many (thousand) clients to share the same ip address.