# Django : Get user IP from development server

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to put the user IP in the page I send to the user.
I've tried like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581997/3156085).

So my view looks like :

```
def yourip(request):
    return HttpResponse("Your IP is : %s" % request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
```

but `request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')` returns `None`.
Is it possible to do this from the development server? Or is the problem elsewhere?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        print "returning FORWARDED_FOR"
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
    elif request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP'):
        print "returning REAL_IP"
        ip = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP')
    else:
        print "returning REMOTE_ADDR"
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Comment: I still get *None* in the page I render.

Comment: Looks like that these headers are not sent with local access.

Comment: I guess it is due to your Network type. If your network type is NAT, you will not get a "real" user IP. If you could explain how your network type is.

Comment: I just run this with the "python manage.py runserver" command.

Comment: Are you using a VirtualMachine which the networking is NAT for the development ? And you are forwarding ports to the ports on the VM ?

Comment: No VM, just the development server.

Comment: Ok, did you try with "ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')" . Try also accessing the server from another machine in the same network, you can for example if you have WIFI connect with your Smartphone and see the results.

Comment: Thank you, REMOTE_ADDR seems to work. :) Can you edit your answer so I can validate?

Comment: @vmonteco I edited my answer :-) Feel free to validate it. Thanks

Comment: The general format of the field is: `X-Forwarded-For: client, proxy1, proxy2` so it needs to be `x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0].strip()` to get client IP and not your server's network proxy IP.

Answer (score 0):

In the development server, you can't get client IP so use [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Usage:
ngrok http <your_development_server PORT>