# How can I log both successful and failed login and logout attempts in Django?

Tags: python, django, logging

I want to record all user login and logout attempts in Django. This record should show a history of all users who logged in/out, IP address and time of login/logout.

The `django_admin_log` table seems to only record ADD/DELETE/CHANGE activities of other models, not a history of user access. I've also already checked the `user_logged_in`, `user_logged_out` signals. It seems that if I will use these signals, I need to create a new table to record history of all user login/logout. Is there a built-in method in Django to do this? Or available packages? I've checked other packages, and those that are related to login attempts only limit failed attempts, but do not record successful logins/logouts.

Answer (score 69):

You could hook up to the provided signals: [django.contrib.auth.signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals)

### Recording to log

```
import logging
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_logged_out, user_login_failed
from django.dispatch import receiver

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged_in_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):    
    # to cover more complex cases:
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    log.debug('login user: {user} via ip: {ip}'.format(
        user=user,
        ip=ip
    ))

@receiver(user_logged_out)
def user_logged_out_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs): 
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    log.debug('logout user: {user} via ip: {ip}'.format(
        user=user,
        ip=ip
    ))

@receiver(user_login_failed)
def user_login_failed_callback(sender, credentials, **kwargs):
    log.warning('login failed for: {credentials}'.format(
        credentials=credentials,
    ))
```

### Recording to model/database

So as this answer has not been accepted so far - here an example that sores the actions in a model instead of logging:

#### Model

```
# <your_app>/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_logged_out, user_login_failed
from django.dispatch import receiver


class AuditEntry(models.Model):
    action = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(self.action, self.username, self.ip)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(self.action, self.username, self.ip)


@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged_in_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):  
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    AuditEntry.objects.create(action='user_logged_in', ip=ip, username=user.username)


@receiver(user_logged_out)
def user_logged_out_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):  
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    AuditEntry.objects.create(action='user_logged_out', ip=ip, username=user.username)


@receiver(user_login_failed)
def user_login_failed_callback(sender, credentials, **kwargs):
    AuditEntry.objects.create(action='user_login_failed', username=credentials.get('username', None))
```

#### Admin

```
# <your_app>/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from models import AuditEntry

@admin.register(AuditEntry)
class AuditEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['action', 'username', 'ip',]
    list_filter = ['action',]
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. I already hooked up to those signals. But to store those activities, does that mean I need to create a new table in my database and store all those activities, or Django has some built-in methods to do this, similar to what django_admin_log is already doing? Thanks again!

Comment: one thing, at the moment it is not possible to log IP for the failed attempts (signal is not providing a request variable); there is a ticket for the solution, but not approved yet; workaround is to raise an exception and handle it in middleware

Comment: @Jerzyk, I checked the django_admin_log table and I'm thinking of adding this in the receiver for user_login/logout: 

`LogEntry.objects.log_action(
            user_id         = request.user.pk, 
            content_type_id = '18',
            object_id       = '1',
            action_flag     = ADDITION,
            object_repr     = '1',
            change_message  = "login"
        )`

Is this the proper way to do it, or it's better that I create a separate table in my database to store the login/logout attempts?

Comment: it is your system, so you can do whatever you want, even you can add more flags as needed, remember that by default there is no "admin" view for this table - only small snipped showing filtered data for the current user, so it may be nice to add a read-only view in the admin...

Comment: @ryan_2016 you should not use hard-coded content type ids. These ids are created during first/subsequent migrations and so they could change (e.g. on a fresh development installation). And yes - I would suggest to create a new model to store these activities.

Comment: @ryan_2016 did you try `request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR').split(',')[0]` for getting logout IPs? Worth marking this as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a new answer integrating with Django user (`AbstractUser`) as below:

**model.py** (Creating a model that inherits from Django user):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class UserModel(AbstractUser):  # Inherit from django user
    last_logout = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.username, self.ip)
```

**Signal.py** (Recording to Django-model and to log):

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils import timezone
from <model> import UserModel  # above model
from logging import getLogger

logger = getLogger(__name__)
  
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip


@receiver(user_logged_out)
def user_logged_out_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    ip = get_client_ip(request)
    username = request.user.username  # get the username.
    now = timezone.now()
    logger.warn('{} logged out with {} IP'.format(user, ip))  # recording to log
    UserModel.objects.filter(username=username).update(last_logout=now,
                                                   status='user_logged_out',
                                                   ip=ip
                                                   )  # recording to the model
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `username` is located in one of the `AbstarctUser` fields.
- User **login time** is built-in Django `AbstractUser`. (Do not need
  to be implemented)
- Also, you can implement **login_faild** in a similar way.

---