# How to get last login ip in django and save to a GenericIPAddressField?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm extending the user profile and added a last_ip field as shown below. How do I update this field whenever a user is logged in to its current IP?  I am using allauth if it matters.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    last_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', verbose_name="Last Login IP")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For actually getting the user IP address you can utilise [django-ipware](https://github.com/un33k/django-ipware). There are other methods but this app seems to cover as much as possible, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django) for the detailed information.

Once you have the USER_IP, you can create a middleware and update the `last_ip` for every request

```
# middleware.py
class LastLoginIP(object):
     def process_request(self, request):
         if request.user.is_authenticated():
            UserProfile.objects\
            .filter(user=request.user)\
            .update(last_ip=USER_IP)

# settings.py add the middleware
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  ....
  your.middleware.LastLoginIP
)
```

---

Alternatively, if you already set up a system that only allows one concurrent login per profile (every time user switches devices, he/she has to login again) , then you can update the `last_ip` during the login.

Comment: Ensure the module path of the new middleware `LastLoginIP` is placed after `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` in  `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, the attribute `user` is added to `request` only after running `AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request()`