# Create a form with one field with a model that has multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So, I want to log the searches which people make (oh noes, I'm the NSA, and all). To that end, I have this Search model:

```
class Search(models.Model):
    search_string = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ip_record = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    date_searched = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

Then, I have this form:

```
class SearchForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Search
        fields = '__all__'
```

How do I make it that there is only the `search_string` displayed? I have tried setting `editable=False` and using only the `search_string` field as a singleton list provided to `fields`, but that doesn't populate the other fields and creates an integrity error:

```
IntegrityError at /endos/
NOT NULL constraint failed: backend_search.ip_record
```

How should I be creating this form? And how do I create it with only one field and with the other fields being populated by computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `SearchForm` `Meta`, write:

```
fields = ('search_string', ) # mind the ,
```

If you only want to put the `search_string` into the form.

But you are not quite done! The problem is - as the `IntegrityError` indicates - that you do not set the `ip_records`, which needs to be set in order for the new `Search` object to be written to the database. To set the field you can save the form without committing, set the `ip_records`, then commit. This all in the view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.ip_record = get_IP(request)  # get_IP is to define (see below)
    obj.save()
```

---

For getting the IP, this might help:

```
def get_IP(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

The function is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4581789/1622937) SO question.