# how to get client side ip address using django application?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have tried using this:

```
ip_address=str(request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
```

But it always return None.
Also I have tried this:

```
ip_address=request.META.get('CF-Connecting-IP', request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'))
```

But it always return 127.0.0.1.
I need client side ip address, not the remote ip address.
Any help would be appreciated.
I need the ipv4 address like [this](https://www.whatismyip.com/).

Comment: This could be useful `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django`

Comment: I did use this before. But it returns 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are you running your code on the local host? because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django will give you the client ip....

Comment: yes, I am running my code on local host. But I have checked on google cloud server and I got client side Ip address. Thanks. You are rignt "Gal"