# Run python application separately on each computer

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a basic django application that runs ifconfig and displays the logs. The app is running from my laptop and all the other laptops connected to the same WiFi network are able to access this application. However, on running the application on other computers, I am getting the same logs that I was getting from my own laptop,ie, I am getting the ip address of my own laptop. Is there a way in which I can get the django app to run individually for each computer?

Comment: ifconfig return the ip of server ip, you get client ip with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django)

Comment: If you only need the ip address of the client then @aliva has the right comment. But if you need more (all of ifconfig and syslogs) then you're out of luck: there's no way you can access this kind of data remotely, luckily! otherwise any web server could access pretty sensitive information about my computer.