# Want to get ip address from user to be manually typed in (not by their location)

Tags: python, html, django

Here's the code

In forms.py

```
from django import forms

class CmdForm(forms.Form):
    ip_address = forms.CharField(label='Enter IP address:')
    command = forms.CharField(label='Command to execute:')
```

In Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from first_app.forms import CmdForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
 my_dict = {'insert_me': ""}
 return render(request,'first_app/index.html',context=my_dict)

def form_name_view(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
     form = CmdForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
        from netmiko import ConnectHandler

        devices = {
        'device_type':'cisco_ios',
        'ip':'ip_address',
        'username':'mee',
        'password':'12345',
        'secret':'12345',

        }
        ipInsert = request.POST.get('ip_address', '')
        cmd = request.POST.get('command', '')
        netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
        #print("connection established with", devices['ip'])
        getIP = netconnect.send_command(ipInsert)
        output = netconnect.send_command(cmd)

        return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'output':output, 'getIP':getIP})
       else:
        form = CmdForm()
       return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form})
   else:
       return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {})
```

however i m getting the error:-

> NetMikoTimeoutException at /Automation_page/
>   Connection to device timed-out: cisco_ios ip_address:22
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Automation_page/
>   Django Version: 2.2.3
>   Exception Type: NetMikoTimeoutException
>   Exception Value:
>   Connection to device timed-out: cisco_ios ip_address:22
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py in establish_connection, line 864
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.7.3
>   Python Path:
>   ['K:\Work\DevNet\first_project',
>    'C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.zip',
>    'C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib',
>    'C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32',
>    'C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages']

why i m getting the time-out though my devices are up and running.

thanx to those willing to help.! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get user IP address in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django)

Comment: nope. its not a duplicate as the  code in link (if u have observed) relates to getting user ip address by their location (not manual typing)  and in my question i want to get ip address to be typed by user as i m an automation engineer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably the line

```
'ip':'ip_address',
```

should read

```
'ip': form.cleaned_data['ip_address'],
```

Comment: thanx for the reply ;-) but i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

the only change i did is:-

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
        ipInsert = request.POST.get('ip_address', '')
        devices = {
        'device_type':'cisco_ios',
        'ip':ipInsert,
        'username':'mee',
        'password':'12345',
        'secret':'12345',

        }
        cmd = request.POST.get('command', '')
        netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
        #print("connection established with", devices['ip'])
        getIP = netconnect.send_command(ipInsert)
        output = netconnect.send_command(cmd)
```

and it works just as i wanted ;-)