# How do i implement fingerprint in Web Application in Laravel or Django

Tags: javascript, php, html, django, laravel

I got a project for school that asked me this stuff:

It is a simple web application for fingerprinting users or visitors. 
Something similar as this one, except that we don't need to check if 
fingerprint is unique.

https://amiunique.org/fp

So the app should be modern and should respond to the visitor details of 
his device (OS, browser, IP address, country, city - this can be done 
via API /maxmind/... and some other information from device)

Here you can use any framework as you want bootstrap or anything else...

Design should be simple - in front page should have one button in the 
middle which says: Scan me or whatever, after clicking all results 
should appear on the page in organized way.

Here is one example of front page: 
https://fingerprintjs.com/open-source/

The purpose of app is to detect if OS is outdated or browser is not 
latest version to inform user in some sort of windows. But that we can 
discuses later.

**Can you provide me some sources on how can i start this fingerprint thing, i have good knowledge of web developing html css js back-end and front-end, but implementing fingerprint is first time in my life. THANKS!!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this javascript code [here](https://codepen.io/run-time/pen/XJNXWV), it's help you to get lot of information about the browser and generate a unique identify as a Fingerprint, so you can try to open the browser in incognito mode and it should still assign you the same fingerprint id.

Foreach information we have a function for example you can get the fingerprint id like this:

```
var fp = new Fingerprint({
  canvas: true,
  ie_activex: true,
  screen_resolution: true
});

var uid = fp.get();
```

Comment: really helpfull even tho i didnt get the thing i want but i have an idea now, for example to get user's IP or Country, how could i manage that?

Comment: For Laravel you can get the helper function that returns a Illuminate\Http\Request and call the function ip() method like that `request()->ip();`
you can check here [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ip) for more details 
and for Django this is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581997/7541313) to do the same thing

Comment: For Country you can check this [package](https://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip) and for Django this object [GeoIP2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoip2/) do the job, both are bases on [MaxMind geoip2 library](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/).

Comment: does GeoIP get users IP or i need first with request then put the ip in GeoIP to get the location?

Comment: For Laravel If the IP not set ($ip == null) the application default to the remote address.
and for Django you need to set the query (in your case the IP address)
`g.country('google.com')`

Comment: bro i would like to chat with u more about this, can u provide me your social media info?

Comment: you can find me [here](https://twitter.com/hamza_makraz) also, don't forget to vote up if my comments help you