# How to sent GET request with some parameters?

Tags: html, django, web

I am new in the web dev. And have some questions. I hope someone can help me.

when I send a get request from an external device to my django server  I do it like that:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)             

s.connect(("127.0.0.1" , 8000))    
s.sendall(b'GET / \n\n')
s.recv(100)
s.close
```

How can I see an address of a machine which sends a GET request to my web server (everything in the local network)?
How can I send some data back to the same machine after receiving the GET request?

I also would like to be able to send a get request with some message what the device needs so the view in django can proccess it. How can I from the GET request with a additional message?

I use django, server and external devices are connected to the same network

thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the following stack overflow link to get the IP address: [How do I get user IP address in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django)
2. The web server(The Django development server/ Nginx/ Apache) will handle the connections to your web application. They will help to send the response back to the same client(same IP) who send the request.
   So you need to write a view function which will return render/HttpResponse/Some other kind of response.

eg:

```
def index(request):
    some_dict = {'ip': '192.168.1.1', }
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', some_dict)
    #return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: great thank you :) It works. And for a different GET request for a specific data I can create a separate views in Django.