# How to just listen to specific ip addresses for calling specific views

Tags: django, django-views

I was wondering if there is a way to listen to ip addresses and judge thereby if a view is allowed to be displayed or not. If so, could you recommend me a good approach for this.
I'm gonna give an example in order to get better understood.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

As to this example, when a certain url pattern is matched, i want for django to check if the requesting pc ip address lies in 'allowed_ips_list'. Im aware of this can be attained inside views but, i was thinking that if i am able to optimize this process it would be better.. than calling a view and checking consecutively.

As always, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

By using decorator:

```
def required_allowed_ips(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        request = args[0]

        ip = get_ip(request)

        # Check if ip is in your allowed_ips_list

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner

# Add decorator to your view
@required_allowed_ips
def test(request):
    pass


def get_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

[get_client_ip()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581997/11220956)

Answer (score 0):

You can write [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) to check if the request is coming from allowed IP and hitting which endpoint. If yes, you can continue with calling view else return HTTP 403 Forbidden status.

Make sure you add this middleware in `MIDDLEWARE` list refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware) for more details

To get client ip use [django-ipware](https://github.com/un33k/django-ipware). According to your test case, please verify whether IP of user you are getting here is what you have kept in `allowd_ips_list`

Here is a sample code for your use case.

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request) #explore `django-ipware` for details
    if not ip or ip not in allowed_ips_list :
        return return HttpResponseForbidden()
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

You can also combine view specific access by checking if `request.path == '/admin/' and ip in allowed_ips_list` and only then allow access.

Restricting access based on client's IP is not a robust solution. Having different user groups, roles and permissions is what you should be doing and Django will help you in that. But if IP is the only option you have left with then custom middleware is the recommended way rather than processing inside view.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by MiddlewareMixin and also check to do it for specific view or app label:

```
class AddIPToRequestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

def process_request(self, request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
    if x_forwarded_for:
        request.ip = x_forwarded_for.split(",")[0]
    else:
        request.ip = request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

also you can to this for specific view or app_labels by resolving request path

```
resolve(request.path)
```

after this you can access to requested ip in view or every where you got the request object `request.ip`