# Getting user's IP after sign up

Tags: django

I have a Django Website and I'm using [IPInfo](https://github.com/ipinfo/django). When the user signs up, I have the following signal:

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def create_profile(request, user, **kwargs):
    ip = request.ipinfo.ip
    city = request.ipinfo.city
    country = request.ipinfo.country
    region = request.ipinfo.region
    timezone = request.ipinfo.timezone
    postal = request.ipinfo.postal
    loc = request.ipinfo.loc
    //Save into DB
```

However, instead of saving the user's details it saves the server's IP, city, etc. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: What signal is this function listening to? The request is not usually passed to any of the pre/post save signals

Comment: The request IP will be the IP of your front-end reverse proxy.  You need to look at how the reverse proxies are configured to find out if they add an attribute to the request header with the *actual* request IP, in it; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django

Comment: @IainShelvington I just updated the question. It is the `AllAuth` User Sign up signal