# Question about getting an IP address in Genie

Tags: python, html, django, web, ip

I am a novice in Django and I got this code from a specialist, but I do not know how it works and how anyone can explain how it works?

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Comment: you would have to learn `HTTP` (HyperText Transfer Protocol) to understand it.

Comment: when client (i.e, web browser) sends request for some page on server then it adds extra information (HTTP headers) and one of them can be `REMOTE_ADDR` with `IP`. If request goes by `proxy server` then `proxy serve` may put its `IP` in `REMOTE_ADDR` and keep original `IP` in `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is important to mention that your code snippet is probably coming from this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django). In case people want to read the whole answer.

*Code followed by explanation:*

```
def get_client_ip(request):
```

Start a function `get_client_ip` with input `request`.

```
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
```

[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) is a field of the [HTTP request header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) that you store in the variable `x_forwarded_for`.

```
if x_forwarded_for:
    ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
```

The variable `x_forwarded_for` is a list of IP addresses separated by comma (example below).

```
203.0.113.195, 70.41.3.18, 150.172.238.178
```

As you are only interested in the first IP address you separate this string by comma `.split(',')` and only take the first object `[0]`.

```
else:
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
```

If the variable `x_forwarded_for` is empty then you try to get the users IP address by taking the data from the **REMOTE_ADDR** field of the **HTTP request header** as this is your second best option.

```
return ip
```

At the end of the function you want to return the IP address so you can use it in your application.