# Getting same IP address for all my devices while getting the META data from the request

Tags: python, django, http, request, ip-address

In my webapp I was getting the IP address of the user system and showing the same in the landing page. However for testing when I am making a request from all my devices at home I see same IP address(49.37.71.31).

2 questions

1. Why is this happening
2. How can I uniquely identify the machine which is making the request to my web app.

**index.html**

```
<div class="button add-list-button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn">{{ ip }}</a>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return render(request, 'index.html', context = {'ip':ip})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get user IP address in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django)

Comment: Nope, please read the question is why all my devices are showinng same IP adress i my webapp