# How to get the Current User IP in Python / Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, ip

I am trying to capture the IP Address and the System Name of the current Login user during the login Process.
I Use following code for the same:

```
import socket
system = socket.gethostname()
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(system)
```

It works fine in Local Server but when I push to Server it takes the server name and server IP instead of user IP.

Comment: Grab the ip from the header in the `request` object, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django

Comment: @JSRB This method returns server IP/IP on which Website is Hosted.
I want to get the client IP not Server IP