# How can I get the client ip address in django?

Tags: python, django

I am building an application in Django that gets the ip address of the user to track their location. And once their location is determined, I want to be able to figure if their signup date coincides with a holiday in their country.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get user IP address in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Client IP is send to your Django application from your web server (Nginx for example)
you can access it in request like this:

```py
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
       ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
       ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```