# make sure that requests to my server come from my site and as a result of user interaction with it

Tags: reactjs, django, security, request, fetch

I made a small react app that sends the following request to my server:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', pdfFileSelected);
formData.append('password', pdfPassword.current);
formData.append('selected_pages', selectedPages);
formData.append('save_separate', saveSeparate.current.checked)

fetch('https://mydomain/pdf-processing/split/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
}).then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

I have the server part on Django.

But the problem is that someone can programmatically send such requests to my server.

I know about the **origin** header in requests, but it can be modified in CLI scripts.
I also tried the **csrf token**, but you can take it from the cookies of your browser and insert it into the form in your script.

Are there any methods to verify that the request came from my domain and as a result of user interaction with the site?
And if there are no such countermeasures to limit third-party requests to my server, then is it possible to simply limit the number of requests per day by IP?

Comment: This is fundamentally not possible using domain-based checks as those are all easily faked.  You can do by IP, which is sub-ideal as you have to keep up with allowed IPs and anyone with a VPN can do what they want.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django. Just to be clear, though:  the IP is going to be by end-user IP, so this will not be effective for any kind of public app.  There is no way to limit interactions with a public site to "just by your React app" and wanting that means removing the ability for a user to control the hardware they own.

Comment: You can use `django-ratelimit` to limiting requests per day based on IP address, user, endpoint or else you can use `django-rest-framework-rate-limiting` to control over rate limiting for API endpoints

Comment: Thank you! @possum, If it is not possible to completely restrict access to my site from third-party requests, then maybe you know of some methods to prevent this at least a little or make this process more difficult?